# Facebook like button for canvas app

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-c#-sdk

I have the following code for the like button:

```
<fb:like data-href="http://foobar.com/Home/View/@Model.News.Id/" send="true" width="320" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
```

When I try to debug this in Facebook Linter. It's failing:

```
Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.
```

When I look at what Facebook returns as a response I see that it's redirecting to authentication page.

This is a canvas app and I have to authenticate the users right. So I have it in every action within controller.

All I want to do is a like button per page which are dynamic.

How can i fix this ? any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem sharing content from "private" site on facebook](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5371617/problem-sharing-content-from-private-site-on-facebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/407/

> Enabling the Like button for canvas URLs on Facebook Based on feedback
>   from the developer community, we’re making it possible to like content
>   within an application on Facebook. Now your users can like pages
>   within your application just as they’ve been doing with Facebook
>   Pages, and other pages on the web.
>
> The resulting News Feed story will link directly back to the
>   application, giving users more opportunities for liking content on
>   Facebook.
>
> To implement this feature, add Open Graph protocol  tags in the
>    of the IFramed page or the canvas endpoint. Your canvas
>   application’s ID will be automatically added as the fb:app_id. The
>   og:url automatically points to your apps.facebook.com URL, and the
>   og:site_name will be filled in as your application’s name.
>
> For example, if you’re interested in gaining distribution for content
>   or giving users the ability to like a virtual good, add the following
>   pieces of the Open Graph protocol:
>
> og:title - The title of your object og:image - An image URL which
>   should represent your object. The image must be at least 50px by 50px
>   and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1. If you have a real-world
>   object that expects to publish updates to users (e.g., a cause, movie,
>   product), include the og:type tag with the appropriate type. You can
>   verify that the Open Graph tags have been entered correctly by using
>   the URL Linter.

For this

> Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.

You should allow linter to access the page to read the og tags. If you page is under user authentication, you should some how allow facebook

> Facebook needs to scrape your page to know how to display it around
>   the site.

The user agent of the scraper is: "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

Answer (score 0):

how and where do you allow the scraper? I have a page where you have to login and i don´t get it to work..

Comment: Ok will see if i can do a solution for this. Thanks.